# 5 player round-robin tournaments

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is there any literature on the order structure coming from round-robin tournaments?  I play games on [littlegolem](http://www.littlegolem.net/) and the tournaments are mostly 5x5 round-robins.  I noticed at the end, after sorting for wins and "sum of scores" all the matrices look the same.
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc|cc}
1 &     & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 8 & 24\\\\
2 &    0 &   & 2 & 2 & 2 & 6 & 12 \\\\
3 &    0 & 0 &   & 2 & 2 & 4 & 4 \\\\
4 &    0 & 0 & 0 &   & 2 & 2 & 0 \\\\
5 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   & 0 & 0
\end{array}$$

Can all tournament grids be ordered this way even for 5x5?  Is there literature on partial orders or well-orders induced from tournaments?

Comment: I can’t say I understand what the last column means, but it is perfectly possible that player A beats player B, player B beats player C, and player C beats player A, in which case the tournament does not induce an order, and the matrix looks different.

Comment: And of course, if it does not contain a cycle like this, the tournament induces a total order. A total order with a given finite number of elements is unique up to isomorphism, hence the tournament matrix can be reordered to the triangular form. Either I am missing something, or this is nowhere near a research-level question.

Comment: In a Martin Gardner column, probably the 1960's or 1970's, he gave diagrams for four ordinary cubical dice with altered numbers, call them A,B,C,D. I think one of them had all numbers the same, each side had the same number (4?). Anyway, he called them "nontransitive," as, when rolled against each other competitively, A beats B 2/3 of the time (by easy counting/finite probability arguments), B beats C 2/3 of the time, then C beats D, finally D beats A, all 2/3 of the time. 

Comment: The last column is "Sum of Opponents' Scores". It can be calculated from the table, and contains no new information. It is used on littlegolem for ordering the players.

Comment: @maproom: Thanks for the information. @Will: The number of nonisomorphic tournaments is given in http://oeis.org/A000568 (and it’s easy to check by hand for these small numbers), there are indeed 4 tournaments with 4 players, and there are 12 with 5 players. Diagrams of all tournaments of up to 6 players are presented in http://oeis.org/A000568/a000568.pdf .